$H^2(X,T_X)=0$ implies the Frölicher spectral sequence degenerates at $E_1$?
Let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, if $X$ satisfies $H^2(X,T_X)=0$, then it is well-known that the Kuranishi space of $X$ is smooth by Kodaira and Spencer's deformation theory. On the other hand, it is proved that if the Frölicher spectral sequence of $X$ degenerates at $E_1$ with the canonical bundle of $X$ being trivial, then the Kuranishi space of $X$ is also smooth, so a natural question is: if $X$ satisfies that $H^2(X,T_X)=0$, do we already have the Frölicher spectral sequence of $X$ degenerates at $E_1$?

Calabi-Eckmann manifolds should give a counterexample.

@GrishaPapayanov, can you elaborate it a bit? Do you mean that for a Calabi-Eckmann manifold $X$,  there is $H^2(X,T_X)=0$ while the Frölicher spectral sequence of $X$ does not degenerate at $E_1$?

Precisely. The spectral sequence was calculated by Borel in A spectral sequence for complex analytic bundles, and the fact that $H^2(X, T) = 0$ is in Ise, Some properties of complex analytic vector bundles over compact complex homogeneous spaces

Wrong link, sorry: the correct one is https://ir.library.osaka-u.ac.jp/repo/ouka/all/9821/omj12_02_01.pdf from Osaka Math. J. The link in the previous comment is to the summary
